# Overflowing horizontal list with Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

OK, let me explain what I'm trying to do:

- I have a `ul` list with items
- Items are of fixed width (and height)
- The list is horizontal
- When the items "overflow" their container, I want them to remain in the same line (and being able to horizontally scroll in the container)

What happens instead:

When there are more items than the containers can handle, the "overflowing" elements move to the line below.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gm32f6fp/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent element i.e `ul` to avoid wrapping to next line

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}
ul#tabs li {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#tabs li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Argh.... I knew it was something simple. Just learned something. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

ul#tabs {
border-bottom:1px solid black;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
width:100%;
white-space: nowrap;
}

ul#tabs::-webkit-scrollbar { 
   /* display: none; */
}

ul#tabs li {
width:150px !important;
height: 30px !important;
padding-top:5px;
border:1px solid red;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
display:inline-block;
}

ul#tabs li:hover {
background: #eee;
color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tabs">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>seven</li>
</ul>
```